# Member login code snippet troubleshooting - I'm very new to this

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create an independent user login portal on my website (Powered by Wix - I'm not a programmer or graphic designer) and I'm having an issue sorting out an error, or rather I'm having an issue understanding the answers I've found relating to the error. Here is the code snippet for reference:

```
    import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
    import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

    $w.onReady(function(){{
        $w('#loginNow').onClick(function (){
            let email = $w('#loginEmail').value;
            let password = $w('#loginPassword').value;
              wixUsers.login(email,password)
            .then(()=>{}
                wixLocation.to('/projects-2/{Project Name}');
            })
        }
    })
```

The issue is that the last line is throwing the following error message:

- Argument of type "void" is not assignable to parameter of the type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike'

From what I've read, this means that the callback function is not working correctly. Understanding that I'm completely green here, the callback functions present are the loginEmail and loginPassword as they have to be referenced against the database, but there's also the callback to the page "/project-2/{Project Name}" Knowing that I copied and pasted the slug exactly it should callback just fine, but it's not.

Hopefully, that makes sense. Any help sorting this out is appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is not formatted correctly. It should be as follows:

```
        .then(() => wixLocation.to('/projects-2/{Project Name}'));
```

Also, I don't think `$w.onReady(function(){{` should have two curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! 

Unfortunately, the limitations on the Wix platform rendered this entire exercise moot. I changed the direction I was going with this and decided that simply setting up a button to redirect to my SharePoint server was the better option.

Comment: @TimMitchell Can you mark as the correct answer by clicking the check then